# Synchronization in QTP

Tags: synchronization, qtp

I am in the middle of a script for a website.  How can I make synchronization with the progress bar in my website?  I am sing QTP 9.5 version.

Comment: Did you try inserting a sync point via the QTP menu? If you did try it, and it's not working, what is actually happening? You will get more and better answers if you more fully describe what you tried, what you expected to happen, and what actually is happening. Just like submitting good bug reports to the development team, the more details you provide, the more likely you are to get the help you need.

Answer (score 1):

There are like a dozen ways to do this, depending on the situation. So, try to view how the progress bar is created and updated.

If the site is programmed in a fashionable way, it is created as an object with an internal status (ie. running from 0 to 9, when the internal status is 9, it displays a full progress bar and the application is ready.).
If this is the case, try to capture the internal object. If you cannot reach it by native QTP, you can also use the Javascript object from the page (see this excellent article: http://www.softwareinquisition.com/-p=81.htm or use QTP11, I just learned from user Motti).

If you need more help on this subject, please post a code/html snippet of the progress bar.

Answer (score 0):

> When progress bar is still running then at the same time you can keep a track on the browser status bar and once the browser status becomes ***"Done"*** or something similar (depends on the application implementation also).
>
> I hope you know how to get Status bar text for comparison. So once Browser status is updated you can continue with next steps till that time wait for that status to change.
>
> To avoid infinite loop, also keep one counter. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
For i = 1 to 10 
 if Browser().progressBar.exist =True then
   wait(10)
if Browser().progressBar.exist =True then
  raise failure "Progress Bar alive for more than 100 seconds"
```

Just add this code .

Answer (score -1):

1. Using Synchronization point :- This is one of the best method, using this we can synchronize against a properity-value pair . For example - We can make QTP wait till any object (say a Dialog after Progress Bar) becomes enable while running the application .

   Or go through this link, It Might help you
       http://www.qtpsudhakar.com/2009/02/synchronization.html.
2. Using .Exist Method - QTP checks for the existence of an object and then operate on them . It will wait for maximum time specified in exist() method ,if object appears before the maximum time, it will move to the next line . For Example -Browser("").Page("").Progress Bar.Exist(5) ,Here QTP will wait maximum 5 seconds for the button to appear .

3.Using Harcoded Wait statement - Least prefered approach .QTP will forcefully wait for the time specified in parenthesis .Some times suppose we have given a wait of 5 secs for any object, but object appear in 2 sec, then still it will wait for extra 3 secs, which is wastage of ti